# ORA-00904: mapping issue causes invalid identifier

Tags: hibernate, mapping, many-to-many, one-to-many, embeddable

I have an issue named for this error message shown below.

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "DETAILORDE1_"."BOOK": invalid identifier
```

What it means is not to map with **Book** and **DetailOrder** class.

I searched many resources to solve it out. I tried many options from them but nothing changed. **pk.book** value cannot be perceived from Book class.

How can I fix it?

Here are the codes shown below.

Book

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BOOK",catalog = "JSPPROJECTDATABASE")
public class Book implements Serializable{
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "pk.book", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<DetailOrder> detailOrders = new HashSet<DetailOrder>();
```

DetailOrder

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DETAIL_ORDER", catalog = "JSPPROJECTDATABASE")
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.orders", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.book", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "BOOK_ID")) })
public class DetailOrder implements Serializable{
...
@EmbeddedId
    public DetailOrderId getPk() {
        return pk;
    }

    public void setPk(DetailOrderId pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }

    @Transient
    public Book getBook() {
        return getPk().getBook();
    }

    public void setBook(Book book) {
        getPk().setBook(book);
    }

    @Transient
    public Orders getOrders() {
        return getPk().getOrders();
    }

    public void setOrders(Orders orders) {
        getPk().setOrders(orders);
    }
```

DetailOrderId

```
@Embeddable
public class DetailOrderId implements Serializable{

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BOOK_ID")
    private Book book;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID")
    private Orders orders;

    public Book getBook() {
        return book;
    }
    public void setBook(Book book) {
        this.book = book;
    }
    public Orders getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }
    public void setOrders(Orders orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem without using composite id .